# Unexpected order of tkinter's event_generate and update commands

Tags: tkinter, unit-testing

I am trying to get tkinter's `event_generate` to work with `update` for atomic unittesting.

The following code does not work as I expect. 'BackSpace event generated.' is not printed. My understanding is that `event_generate` places the event in tkinter's event queue and then `update` should clear and execute all of the events in the queue.

```
class UpdWin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bind('<BackSpace>',
                  lambda event: print(event.keysym, 'event generated.'))


app = UpdWin()
app.event_generate('<BackSpace>')
app.update() # Update doesn't work if placed here
```

However, the following code does print 'BackSpace event generated.' Events in the event queue are cleared and executed during `__init__`. After this the main code places the event into tkinter's queue.

```
class UpdWin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bind('<BackSpace>',
                  lambda event: print(event.keysym, 'event generated.'))
        self.update()  # Update works if placed here


app = UpdWin()
app.event_generate('<BackSpace>')
```

My first thought was that my understanding of the `update` command had to be wrong. Both Lundh, Shipman and the TclCmd man page have different entries for `update`.

> Process all pending events, call event callbacks, complete any pending geometry management, redraw widgets as necessary, and call all pending idle tasks. [Lundh (1999)](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/tkinter/x8996-event-processing.htm)
>
> This method forces the updating of the display. [Shipman (New Mexico Tech)](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)
>
> This command is used to bring the application “up to date” by entering the event loop repeatedly until all pending events (including idle callbacks) have been processed. [TclCmd man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/update.htm)

From this I suspected an undocumented timing problem and I tried a third location for the update command. The following code also works.

```
class UpdWin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bind('<BackSpace>',
                  lambda event: print(event.keysym, 'event generated.'))


app = UpdWin()
app.update() # Update works if placed here
app.event_generate('<BackSpace>')
```

Why does tkinter's `update` work when it's called before `event_generate` but not after?

**Edit**

The following code will print "BackSpace event generated." if `app.update` is in position 1.
It will print "FocusIn event generated." if `app.update` is in position 2.
NB: Bryan Oakley's response suggests this effect may be machine dependent.

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
# app.update()  # Position 1
app.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda event: print('FocusIn event generated.'))
app.bind('<BackSpace>', lambda event: print(event.keysym, 'event generated.'))
app.event_generate('<BackSpace>')
app.update()  # Position 2
```

The following code using `when='tail'` never prints "BackSpace event generated." whether `app.update` is in position 1 or 2.

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
app.update()  # Position 1
app.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda event: print('<FocusIn> event generated.'))
app.bind('<BackSpace>', lambda event: print(event.keysym, 'event generated.'))
app.event_generate('<BackSpace>', when="tail")
# app.update()  # Position 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't duplicate your observations, so I can't say for certain what is going on. There's obviously a little code that is missing, and this potentially could also be affected by the platform you're running on and how you're launching the program.

However, I think the problem is boils down to three factors:

1. By default, `event_generate` immediately processes any handlers for the event (ie: `update` and `mainloop` aren't required *per se*)
2. By *not* calling `update()` *before* calling `event_generate` the window isn't drawn, and when the window isn't drawn the OS or window manager won't give it keyboard focus.
3. If the app doesn't have keyboard focus, Tkinter is likely going to ignore keyboard events.

That may not entirely be the case -- since you tell it which window is to receive the event, focus might not be a consideration. However, visibility of the window may still play a part. It may be that tkinter logic says to ignore events on invisible windows. It's also possible that your window manager / OS might not be running the program in the foregound -- keyboard focus may be on some other application until you manually click in the window (this seems to be the behavior on OSX, for example).

You might try using the `when` argument to `event_generate`. This lets you defer processing of the handlers until after any other queued events have been processed. Do that, and then call `update()`, and perhaps your code will work. For example:

```
app.event_generate('<Backspace>`, when="tail")
app.update()
```

You might also try to force your app to the foreground with a call to `app.focus_force()` before trying to generate events.

When generating keyboard events, you might also want to generate a `<FocusIn>` event first. When you start generating events, you need to make sure the events you generate behave as much like user generated events as possible, which means you need to be aware of visibility, keyboard focus and mouse focus. Many years ago when I went down this path I remember having to generate `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events when handling buttons, for example, since the built-in bindings sometimes depended on these setting the state of the button to "active".

The definitive documentation for the `event_generate` command is the [Tcl/Tk man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/event.htm#M7).

Comment: I tried every combination of `<FocusIn>`, `focus_set`, `focus_force`, and `<Enter>`. None had any effect. With `when='tail'` it didn't matter where `update` was put; nothing was printed. Whatever's happening it's consistent on my machine: Python 3.4 on MS Windows 7 on a multi-processor. However, if you can't reproduce this effect it's clearly not a reliable method for unittesting.

Comment: @lemi57ssss: can you update your question to have a complete, runnable example that illustrates how you're using the `tail` option? I'm assuming that with the `tail` option you're eventually calling `update` or `mainloop` after generating the event(s), but maybe I'm making a bad assumption.

Comment: I've added an example as requested. With `app.update` in position 2, it follows `event_generate`.  
You're probably aware of this discussion of update (http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255) but I'm linking for anybody else that may be interested.