# How to functional test if tkinter bind works

Tags: python, tkinter, model-view-controller, pytest, tdd

I'm working on an application with the tkinter graphical user interface. With the MVC pattern. I am partially using TDD - I realize that it is unnecessary for GUI build part. However, I assume that I need to automate the testing of controller duties. Most of which rely on passing data from view to model.

Passing process should be initialize by losing focus by entry widget, or by pressing Enter key. In my application there will be few different types of data to pass, so I decided to subclass widgets that have to initialize passing variables process.

Sidenote: I found a topic, [Tkinter's event_generate command ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581864/tkinters-event-generate-command-ignored) where OP points in addendum that subclassing widgets is not a good idea. Nonetheless I don't know how to avoid it and still provide that many different widgets would have a standardized method to return different types of data.

Minimal reproducible example (main.py):

```
import tkinter as tk


class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.pass_value_to_model)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.view.quit()
        del self

    def run_gui(self):
        self.view.mainloop()

    def pass_value_to_model(self, value):
        self.model.variable = value
        print(f"changed model variable value to : {self.model.variable}")

class CustomEntry(tk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = args[0]

    def pass_value(self, event):
        self.parent.passing_method(self.get())

class View(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, passing_method):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.passing_method = passing_method
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.variable = tk.StringVar(self.frame)
        self.entry = CustomEntry(self.frame, textvariable=self.variable)
        self.entry.pack(padx=100, pady=100)

        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.entry.pass_value)
        self.entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.entry.pass_value)


class Model():

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "init value"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = App()
        app.run_gui()
```

And this is working as I expect. Model variable is changing it's value properly. The problem is how to test this.

Here's what I wrote in pytest (test_module.py):

```
import main

def test_passing_value():

    with main.App() as controller:
        test_value = "test"
        controller.view.variable.set(test_value)
        controller.view.entry.event_generate("<Return>")

        assert controller.model.variable == test_value
```

`event_generate` is not working. I suppose, that is because pytest don't start mainloop. If i code this - I can't automatically kill it. What I need to do to automate testing of this passing process?

python version is 3.7

Comment: _"OP points in addendum that subclassing widgets is not a good idea. "_ - I think the OP in this context is wrong. There are plenty of good reasons for subclassing tkinter wigdet classes.

Comment: Have you tried calling `controller.update()` after generating the event? Tkinter's event loop needs to be able to process the event, otherwise the event just sits in a queue forever.

Comment: @BryanOakley ```update()``` doesn't change anything