# How can I set the default container in a decorator class for tkinter.Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, proxy, decorator

I would like to create a contractible panel in a GUI, using the Python package `tkinter`.

My idea is to create a decorator for the `tkinter.Frame`class, adding a nested frame and a "vertical button" which toggles the nested frame.

**Sketch:** (Edit: The gray box should say *Parent of contractible **panel***)

[image]

I got it to toggle just fine, using the nested frame's `grid_remove` to hide it and then move the button to the left column (otherwise occupied by the frame).

Now I want to be able to use it like any other `tkinter.Frame`, but let it target the nested frame. Almost acting like a proxy for the nested frame. For example, adding a `tkinter.Label` (the green `Child component` in the sketch) to the decorator should add the label to the nested frame component (light yellow `tk.Frame` in the sketch) not the decorator itself (strong yellow `ContractiblePanel` in the sketch).

---

**Minimal example:** (omitting the toggling stuff and any "formatting"):

([Here's a published (runnable) *Repl* project](https://replit.com/@smartskaft2/tkinterframedecorator?v=1))

```py
import tkinter

class ContractiblePanel(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._panel  = tkinter.Frame(self)
        self._toggle = tkinter.Button(self, text='<', command=self._toggle_panel)

        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._toggle.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')

    def _toggle_panel(self):
        # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry('128x128')
    
    contractible_panel = ContractiblePanel(root)
```

---

Forwarding configuration calls is just overriding the `config` method I guess?

```py
class ContractiblePanel(tkinter.Frame):
    # ...
    def config(self, **kwargs):
        self._panel.config(**kwargs)

# ...
contractible_panel.config(background='blue')
```

---

But I would like to be able to add a child component into the nested panel frame by

```py
    label_in_panel = tkinter.Label(contractible_panel, text='yadayada')
```

---

**How do I get the `ContractiblePanel` object to act like a proxy to its member `_panel`, when adding child components?**

**What other methods/use cases should I consider?** I am quite new to `tkinter` and thus expect the current implementation to break some common practices when developing `tkinter` GUIs.

Comment: You mention wanting to make a decorator. Do you really need a decorator on a standard frame, or will a custom class be a reasonable solution?

Comment: No I do not really _need_ it to be a decorator. I mostly chose the decorator pattern for practice. I could easily use composition instead of inheritance and just add the method calls I need to use the panel. However, it _would_ be nice to use it as any other `tkinter` component. The code using it would flow better.

Comment: Apparently, one can get issues with the `tkinter` event loops when using inheritance of its components. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581864 : _The problem posed by this six year old question is entirely avoided by better program design in which tkinter widget objects are never subclassed_

Comment: @BryanOakley however, if you suggest a custom class inheriting some `tkinter` component base class, I'm all in! Any pointers to such base class would help a lot. TkDocs tend to be a bit thin IMO.

Comment: The term **decorator** has a meaning for programmers and I'm really not sure if you are referring to it. What do you mean by **decorator** ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs I refer to a class which satisfies the same class interface as another class and that adds some functionality to said interface, before forwarding any calls to the extended class. If that makes sense. My goal was a Frame subclass that added a button on the side which hid the frame. I guess one could argue how much of a decorator it would be, but in my mind I think of it as such. Like the classical example of a border around a text field in some editor.

Comment: When using defined terms like **decorator** or **proxy** you make people wonder what you might mean with it. At least for me your question seems pretty confusing. I think, I know what you are up to and will write an example FWIW.

Comment: @Smartskaft2: I think you're drawing the wrong conclusion from that quote. There's absolutely nothing wrong with subclassing tkinter widgets. What is wrong is calling `update`. Unless you fully understand what is happening when you call that, you can cause yourself problems.

Comment: @Smartskaft2 I have written some code that behaves like you stated in your bottom-line of your question. However I would consider it as anti-pattern and [design-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_smell).

Comment: @BryanOakley Another valid concern about subclassing `tkinter.Something` is that one can easily overwrite internals. Namely `_options` or `_w` and depending on what you know or do about tkinter many more things. A wrapper class might be better for beginners to be honest, even if I will continue using subclasses, since it's cleaner in my view.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: what you write is true about subclassing anything. You are correct, though, that care must be taken that you don't overwrite important private components used by the base classes which are not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Unfortunately, tkinter really isn't designed to support what you want. I think it would be less complicated to simply expose the inner frame and add widgets to it.

That being said, I'll present one possible solution. It's not implemented as a python decorator, but rather a custom class.

The difficulty is that you want the instance of the custom class to represent the outer frame in one context (for example, when packing it in your UI) and the inner frame in another context (when adding child widgets to it)

The following solution solves this by making the instance be the inner frame, and then overriding `pack`,`place`, and `grid` so that they operates on the outer frame. This works fine, with an important exception: you cannot use this class directly inside a notebook or embedded in a text widget or canvas.

I've used colors and borders so it's easy to see the individual components, but you can remove the colors in production code, obviously. Also, I used a label instead of a button since I created the screenshot on OSX where the background color of a button can't be changed.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ContractiblePanel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self._frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(self._frame, bd=2, relief="solid", bg="#EFE4B0")
        self._button = tk.Label(
            self._frame, text="<", bg="#00A2E8", bd=2,
            relief="solid", font=("Helvetica", 20), width=4
        )
        self._frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns", padx=4, pady=4)
        super().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=4, pady=4)
        self._button.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.toggle())

    def collapse(self):
        super().grid_remove()
        self._button.configure(text=">")

    def expand(self):
        super().grid()
        self._button.configure(text="<")

    def toggle(self):
        self.collapse() if self.winfo_viewable() else self.expand()

    def pack(self, **kwargs):
        # override to call pack in the private frame
        self._frame.pack(**kwargs)

    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        # override to call grid in the private frame
        self._frame.grid(**kwargs)

    def place(self, **kwargs):
        # override to call place in the private frame
        self._frame.place(**kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
cp = ContractiblePanel(root, bg="yellow", bd=2, relief="raised")
cp.pack(side="left", fill="y", padx=10, pady=10)

label = tk.Label(cp, text="Child component", background="#22B14C", height=3, bd=2, relief="solid")
label.pack(side="top", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think this answers the question better. It is less complicated and more explicitly as what I did.

Comment: The key parts are the first couple of lines in the `__init__` function, creating a frame in the given parent and _then_ initialize `self` in the intermediate frame. I just realized this stupidly simple change lying in bed. And of course you had directly caught up on it. Thank you for making such a nice realization of my sketch, your code is very clean. I will definitely "borrow" from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is kinda gross to use this code and it's very confusing. So I'm really not sure if you really want to take this route. However, it is possible to achieve it.

The basic idea is to have a **wrapper** and to pretend the wrapper is the actual object you can lie with `__str__` and `__repr__` about what the class really is. That is not what a proxy means.

```
class WrapperClass:

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self._wrapped_frame = tk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
        self._panel = tk.Frame(self._wrapped_frame)
        self._toggle = tk.Button(self._wrapped_frame, text='<', command=self._toggle_panel)

        self._wrapped_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._toggle.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')
        return None

    def _toggle_panel(self):
        print('toggle')

    def __str__(self):
        return self._panel._w
    __repr__ = __str__
```

You can do even more confusing things by **delegate** the lookup-chain to the `_wrapped_frame` inside the `WrapperClass` this enables you to call on the instance of `WrapperFrame()` methods like `pack` or every other method. It kinda works similar for inheritance with the difference that by referring to the object, you will point to different one.

### I don't recommend using this code by the way.

```
import tkinter as tk

NONE = object()
#use an object here that there will no mistake

class WrapperClass:

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self._wrapped_frame = tk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
        self._panel = tk.Frame(self._wrapped_frame)
        self._toggle = tk.Button(self._wrapped_frame, text='<', command=self._toggle_panel)

        self._wrapped_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
        self._toggle.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')
        return None

    def _toggle_panel(self):
        print('toggle')

    def __str__(self):
        return self._panel._w
    __repr__ = __str__

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        #when wrapper class has no attr name
        #delegate the lookup chain to self.frame
        inreturn = getattr(self._wrapped_frame, name, NONE)
        if inreturn is NONE:
            super().__getattribute__(name)
        return inreturn

root = tk.Tk()
wrapped_frame = WrapperClass(root, bg='red', width=200, height=200)
root.mainloop()
```